# PHP: strtotime() gives me wrong timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

This is my code:

```
$testtime = str_replace('.', '-', '2009.07.08 17:01');
$timestamp = strtotime($testtime);
echo $timestamp . "\n";
echo $testtime . "\n";
echo date('Y-m-d H:t', $timestamp);
```

And this is my output:

> 1247065260
>
> 2009-07-08 17:01
>
> 2009-07-08 17:31

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parameters for `date()` are wrong. You should use `date('Y-m-d H:i', $timestamp)`.

`t` is the number of days of the current month, therefore `31`.

Comment: Haha ops, I mixed that up - how embarrassing. Thank you!